# Android: Display and Hide Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager, android-framelayout

I have inside some `Activity` single full screen `Fragment`. Inside that `Fragment` I have another `Fragment` overlaying bottom part of the screen. So in the top part of the screen I have `Button` controlling Visible/Hide of the inner `Fragment`:

1. Layout of the containing `Fragment`:

   ```
   ...
   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/inner_fragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/top_part"
       android:name="com.package.InnerFragment" />
   ```
2. The controlling `Button`:

   ```
   controlButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (!isInnerVisible) showHideInnerFragment("show");
           else showHideInnerFragment("hide");
       }
   });
   ```
3. The helper method `showHideInnerFragment`:

   ```
   private void showHideInnerFragment(String param) {
       //variables are class members...
       fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       innerFragment = new InnerFragment();
       if (param.equals("show")) {
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.inner_fragment, innerFragment);
           isInnerVisible = true;
       } else {
           fragmentTransaction.remove(innerFragment);
           isInnerVisible = false;
       }
       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
   ```

Well - This totally not working...

Comment: showHideInnerFragment() or showHideGroupsFragment()?

Comment: @mjp66 typo fixed....

Comment: Thanks! I'll post an answer in a minute but it looks like you're only calling the method with your param always passing as "show"

Comment: @mjp66 right I changed the if condition now it should be with the right "toggle" logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your isInnerVisible is always false (I'm assuming it starts off as false), which removes the fragment but keeps isInnerVisible false. You probably just need to switch that around:

```
private void showHideInnerFragment(String param) {
    //variables are class members...
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    innerFragment = new InnerFragment();
    if (param.equals("show")) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.inner_fragment, innerFragment);
        isInnerVisible = false;
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(innerFragment);
        isInnerVisible = true;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I would also pass a true/false value to the parameter rather than a string value, it makes it much easier to understand what the code is doing, as it is now it sort of doesn't make sense. I'll update with an example in a bit ;)

edit: here's a nicer way to do what you want:

```
controlButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showHideInnerFragment(isInnerVisible);
    }
});
```

---

```
private void showHideInnerFragment(boolean isVisible) {
    //variables are class members...
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    innerFragment = new InnerFragment();
    if (isVisible == false) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.inner_fragment, innerFragment);
        isInnerVisible = true;
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(innerFragment);
        isInnerVisible = false;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. I suspect that the use of `FragmentManager` add and remove methods is incorrect and should be other method?

Comment: Hmmm. I once did something similar to what you're trying to do and didn't have problems. It's possible I'm not seeing something obvious. How about posting the xml just for kicks?